# How to create a working drag and drop to upload view in MVC that works in IE9 without Silverlight dependencies?

Tags: file-upload, drag-and-drop, internet-explorer-9

I intend to create an ASP.Net MVC form that does the following:

1) Allows the user to drag a file from windows explorer into IE9

2) Once dropped in IE9, the file will then upload

3) The solution must not depend on Silverlight (due to the fact customers would not already have it installed) or Java applets. However, it is acceptable for it to be polyfilled by Flash.

4) I am only interested in free solutions. So, I am not interested in buying a third party licence, etc.

I have been searching online and I found many solutions for HTML5 enabled browsers. However, as IE9 does not support the necessary HTML5 features, nothing seems to work in IE9.

**EDIT**

It must be able to obtain sufficient information about the file to be uploaded from being dropped onto the form.

Answer (score 0):

Hate to tell you the bad news but IE9 does not support the HTML5 drag and drop file upload functionality. This will severely limit your options.

You seem to have found something in Silverlight that works. I could also imagine an ActiveX control working as well. But ActiveX is highly frowned upon, and will cost you money to get the certificates. Either way, some software will have to execute within the browser to provide this functionality since it is not native within IE9.

I think your best bet is to provide the best uploading experience you can with a uploader script like [SWFUpload](http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/) or [plUpload](http://www.plupload.com/).

Comment: This supposedly supports drag and drop plus file uploading for IE6+ - However, I cannot get it work: http://proger.i-forge.net/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%B1/FileDrop/demo/index.html

Comment: So, dragging and dropping must be supported in IE9 through an IFrame... There must be a way to do this, as SWFUpload does not support dragging and dropping for IE9 and pIUpload is not free.

Comment: I'm not having much luck getting that demo to work in IE9 (with and without drag and drop). And plUpload is free licensed via GPLv2.

Comment: I've tried plupload (queue_widget.html); as it says, it doesn't support drag and drop for flash or silverlight. It doesn't detect gears or browserplus but customer's wouldn't be able to install either of those on their works machine. So, plupload isn't an option either.

Comment: As I said earlier, I don't know if you can can do this reliable/successfully in native IE9 because of the missing APIs. Install a plugin or degrade to a standard upload box.

Comment: eithe way it does not work or answer the question - thanks for your efforts